# Singular Value Decomposition with LAPACK: problems with big matrices

Tags: python, c++, lapack, svd, lapacke

I am using the C interface of LAPACK to compute the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) of a matrix. To do so, I am using the routine `dgesvd_`.

I have created a simple C++ script which creates a random matrix (with `M` rows and `N` columns), and that computes its SVD. The code of this script is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include "lapacke.h"

#define M 150
#define N 3
#define MEAN 0
#define STD 0.25


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(MEAN, STD);

    int m = M, n = N, lda = M, ldu = M, ldvt = N, info, lwork;
    double wkopt;
    double* work;
    double s[n], u[ldu * m], vt[ldvt * n], a[lda * n];

    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < (lda * n); k++){
        a[k] = distribution(generator);
    }

    lwork = -1;
    dgesvd_("All", "All", &m, &n, a, &lda, s, u, &ldu, vt, &ldvt, &wkopt, &lwork, &info);
    lwork = (int)wkopt;
    work = (double*) malloc(lwork * sizeof(double));
    dgesvd_("All", "All", &m, &n, a, &lda, s, u, &ldu, vt, &ldvt, work, &lwork, &info);  

    if(info > 0){
        std::cerr<< "The algorithm computing SVD failed to converge\n"     ;
        exit(1);
    }

    free(work);

    std::cout<<"Singular values:\n";
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        std::cout<<s[k]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    return(0);
}
```

A matrix with 150 rows and 3 columns seems to compute the SVD correctly. However, when the matrix has a bigger number of rows (for example, a matrix with 1500 rows and 3 columns), the execution of the compiled script raises this error: *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*.

I tried to do something similar in a Python script:

```
import numpy as np
M = 1500
N = 3
MEAN = np.zeros(3)
STD = 0.25
result = np.linalg.svd(points)
```

When I use Python, the singular values seems to be computed correctly whithout any error, although the NumPy method that I used is performed using the LAPACK routine `dgesdd_` (I tried this and the same error is raised).

Does anyone know why is this error happening? Any help to solve the issue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Pd: I am using version 3.6.0 of lapacke, and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, why are you using `malloc` instead of `new[]`, or even better `std::vector`? Especially since you don't include the correct header file for `malloc`, and might miss its prototype which might lead to big trouble.

Comment: Although technically you're not programming in C++ since you use [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which are not in C++ (it's an extension of whatever compiler you're using).

Comment: Lastly, what do you mean by "raises an error"? *What* error? From *where*? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I was using malloc because I needed pointers for the LAPACK routines. I would try to do what you have suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify the error. Now I have added a more detailed description of what is happening on the question.

Comment: A segmentation fault is a *crash*, and means you are likely doing something wrong with memory or pointers. If you run in a debugger, where in your code does the crash happens? Also, a pointer to memory is a pointer to memory. If you pass one to a C function the memory it points to doesn't *have* to be allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: You are allocating large structures on the stack, such as `u[ldu * M]` is `8 * 1500 * 1500 = 18 MB`.  You should avoid that and instead allocate `u` on the heap.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it. I allocated the matrices ``s``, ``u``, ``vt`` and ``a`` on the heap using ``new[]``  and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocating the matrices on the heap like this solves the problem:

```
double* s = new double[n];
double* u = new double[ldu * m];
double* vt = new double[ldvt * n];
double* a = new double[lda * n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `lapacke.h` and you can see wrappers that take care of work calculations. This is handy because these can change between releases. The overhead is negligible.

```
lapack_int LAPACKE_sgesdd( int matrix_layout, char jobz, lapack_int m,
                           lapack_int n, float* a, lapack_int lda, float* s,
                           float* u, lapack_int ldu, float* vt,
                           lapack_int ldvt );
```

The first argument is `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR` or `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR` depending on your language/platform. An example is shown [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/code-samples-lapack/2023-1/lapacke-sgesdd-example-c-row.html).